# How to check List size in aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration

I am showing list of opportunity in a Lightning component. And I want to display them if the opportunity list size > 0 . i.e here (  opportunityList > 0)

```
<lightning:select name="selectOpportunity" label="" required="false">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.opportunityList}" var="opp">
                <option value="{!opp.Id}" text="{!opp.Name}"></option>
            </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a handful of ways, but the most robust would probably be to see if it's `not(empty(...))`:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.opportunityList))}"> ...
```

This will suppress rendering if the list is empty, or null, or undefined...

Comment: I was going to suggest `.length > 0` but this is much better

Comment: Great !! it works

Comment: @Sebastian Kessel , what is the other way?

Comment: `{!v.opportunityList.length &gt; 0}` but I would go with the suggested solution. It is much better, because it accounts for null/undefined.

Comment: can we get the length of an object element inside lightning component alone?

Comment: @cookie Objects don't have a length, but we can get the length of an Array (List) or String.